# Displaying UIImageView in a subclass of UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a property of DotImageView in my UITableViewCell subclass.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *DotImageView;
```

I try to display it like this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
static NSString *TargetCellIdentifier = @"TargetDetailTableViewCellIdentifier";
    TargetDetailTableViewCell *cell = (TargetDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TargetCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TargetDetailTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    cell = self.TargetCell;
    self.TargetCell = nil;
}
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

Target *aTarget = [targetDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:section]];

if (row == 0) {
        UIImage *dot;
        if (aTarget.importance == high) {
            dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_red.png"];
        }
        else {
            dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_gray.png"];
        }
        UIImageView *variantImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:dot];
        cell.DotImageView = variantImageView;
        [variantImageView release];
        return cell;
```

I do not see any image in my cell.  The other labels of my subclass of UITableViewCell do get displayed.  Am I missing something with UIImageView?  I'm not super familiar with it.  Thanks.

Comment: cell.DotImageView its created? maybe you forgot to link it in the xib

Comment: when you say : "I have a property of DotImageView in my UITableViewSubclass" it's UITableViewCell ? i think we need to see your UITableViewCell declaration in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @Ernesto I checked the nib and it looks connected

Comment: @TheRonin Yes I meant the subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: where you have instantiate `self.TargetCell` ??

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I have an outlet to it in this class.  I use instantiateWithOwner to instantiate the nib.  Like I said, the cell gets created and I can change the labels to it. I just can't change the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as

```
if (row == 0) {
        UIImage *dot;
        if (aTarget.importance == high) {
            dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_red.png"];
        }
        else {
            dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot_gray.png"];
        }
        cell.DotImageView.image = dot;
        return cell;
```

what you was doing is you are assigning new UIImageView object to `cell.DotImageView` now your cell.DotImageView is pointing to this local image view object not to that object which is on xib

Comment: He's binding the cell to an outlet called TargetCell on the view controller and then loading the cell into that property. It's a valid approach and a bit more type-safe than the objectAtIndex version (what if the cell isn't the first object in the nib, for example), but I agree, your approach is a lot less code and works just as well in most cases. I don't think that is why his code doesn't work however.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
[cell.DotImageView setImage:dot];
```

I'm not sure why it works vs the other method I originally had.

Comment: It doesn't work in the original because when you replace the imageView of the cell you also need to add your new imageView as a subview of the cell, otherwise it's just a property of the cell, it's not actually in the view hierarchy. To be honest though, I'd stick with the latter approach - much easier.

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Basic case**

Simply use the image property of the standard UITableViewCell. It is suitable for most cases.

**2 - Your custom case**

Take care, your property is a simple reference to your imageView. So changing its value does not replace the initial one in the subviews tree. Instead, keep your imageView and just set its UIImage property would be better.

```
yourImageView.image = aNewImage.
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert into TargetDetailTableViewCell Class the method:

```
- (void)setDotImage:(UIImage*)dot{



[self.DotImageView setImage:dot];


}
```

It works for me. I hope it can help you!